# How to download Bitcoin block headers from Blockchain.info and save to file?

Tags: api, blockchain.info

I am just developing and testing Bitcoin mining application in plain Javascript
(slow but can be run off-line).

To test it to work correctly I need to download Bitcoin block headers
from Blockchain.info , 6 input parameters .

Are you aware how to call Blockchain API 
https://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_api

I don't use Bitcoin address, no other mining app, just need to download
a number block headers from hashed blocks.

Any idea, demo, example or csv file coming with 6 input parameters
as described in Bitcoin hashing algorithm

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Block_hashing_algorithm

Comment: ever thought of using testnet?

Comment: It might be easier to test (and more profitable to run) should you target an alt-coin rather than Bitcoin

Answer (score 2):

You can download the blockchain headers [using ElectrumX](https://electrumx-spesmilo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/protocol-methods.html#blockchain-block-header). The data is binary packed, but can be deserialized easily enough. You seem to be trying to solo mine, which is a bad idea at the best of times, let alone with JavaScript. You also seems to be trying to build a SPV client. An easier way would just be to use https://blockchain.info/latestblock to get the lastblock hash and use that.

Comment: Anyone have writeups on how to ingest the binary packed electrum data, or at least more info on what it is, exactly?

Comment: The data is the "block header" struct exactly -- https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#Block_Headers has the documentation.  It's a fixed-length binary struct described there.

Comment: https://headers.electrum.org/blockchain_headers is no longer found in DNS.
Is there a replacement?

Comment: @nealmcb https://electrum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/protocol.html#blockchain-block-get-header perhaps...